# Issue with QGIS modeler raster calculator

Tags: qgis, wms, raster-calculator, ndvi, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to apply a formula to scale an NDVI map from a WMS with QGIS modeler, but it keeps throwing me an error. I tried to do this without the modeler and it works.
Here are the steps I want to accomplish in the QGIS modeler:

1. Apply the algorithm "map to raster" to my NDVI map (previously added to my project)  with a predefined resolution (since I'm working with small areas, I set it to 1 unit map per pixel)
2. With the algorithm "raster calculator", apply the recommended formula from the website I downloaded the NDVI, to the NDVI generated in the previous step. The formula is: **(1 * BandaTriada - 100) / 100**, where **BandaTriada** means my "OUTPUT@1"

At this point I already have the NDVI as I want it to be. All that's left is adding my NDVI style to the raster layer generated, with the  set style to raster layer algorithm.

The script gets stuck while performing the raster calculator part - the error I'm getting is:

```
Versión de QGIS: 3.10.4-A Coruña
Revisión del código de QGIS: 10bc9f2ff2
Versión de Qt: 5.11.2
Versión de GDAL: 3.0.4
Versión de GEOS: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Versión de PROJ: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020
Procesando algoritmo...
Algoritmo 'modelo' comenzando…
Parámetros de entrada:
{ 'Extension' : '312455.56408728764,313833.46447932476,4606153.619686341,4607207.818906171 [EPSG:25831]', 'NDVImapWMS' : 'crs=EPSG:25831&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=ox3dndvi2019&styles&url=http://geoserveis.icgc.cat/icc_ortoxpres/wms/service?', 'qgis:rastercalculator_1:NDVI scaled' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Preparar algoritmo: qgis:rasterize_1
Ejecutando Map to raster [1/3]
Parámetros de entrada:
{ EXTENT: '312455.56408728764,313833.46447932476,4606153.619686341,4607207.818906171 [EPSG:25831]', LAYER: 'crs=EPSG:25831&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=ox3dndvi2019&styles&url=http://geoserveis.icgc.cat/icc_ortoxpres/wms/service?', MAKE_BACKGROUND_TRANSPARENT: False, MAP_THEME: '', MAP_UNITS_PER_PIXEL: 1, OUTPUT: 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/processing_ca25d8d8ef7c438194bb38a19eb91be7/24fdd4b2efac401d814bf96c14b56787/OUTPUT.tif', TILE_SIZE: 1024 }
OK. La ejecución tardó 20.074 s (1 salidas).
Preparar algoritmo: qgis:rastercalculator_1
Ejecutando Raster calculator [2/3]
Parámetros de entrada:
{ CELLSIZE: 1, CRS: 'ProjectCrs', EXPRESSION: '(1 * \"\'Capa de salida\' from algorithm \'Map to raster\'@1\" - 100) / 100', EXTENT: 'C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ca25d8d8ef7c438194bb38a19eb91be7/24fdd4b2efac401d814bf96c14b56787/OUTPUT.tif', LAYERS: '', OUTPUT: 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
An error occurred while performing the calculation
Se encontró un error al ejecutar Raster calculator
Se encontró un error al ejecutar Raster calculator
La ejecución falló después de 20.24 segundos

Cargando las capas resultantes
Las siguientes capas no se generaron correctamente.<ul><li>C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp/processing_ca25d8d8ef7c438194bb38a19eb91be7/79264905edc3416891cf30ddd1d56e06/OUTPUT.tif</li></ul>Puede comprobar el «Panel de mensajes del registro» en la ventana principal de QGIS para encontrar más información sobre la ejecución del algoritmo.
```

I have to say that I also had to tweak the "cellsize" and "CRS" options from the raster calculator, since I was getting an error aswell if I lefted it without any value or CRS. Not sure if it helps:

```
No reference layer selected nor CRS provided 
No reference layer selected nor cellsize value provided
```